# Changing some data types in a list while preserving the order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, floating-point, int

If I have a list of numbers, for example:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.43, 1.0, 8.0, 4.0, 8.98, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0, 72.0, 
 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.7, 43.0, 5.89, 5.0, 5.0, 
 5.0, 322.0, 7.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 102.0]
```

Is it possible to convert anything ending in '.0' to an integer and leave numbers like 8.98 as floats while keeping the order of the list?

The output from this should be

```
[1, 3, 1, 1.43, 1, 8, 4, 8.98, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 72, 3, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 4, 4, 4, 
 4, 8.7, 43, 5.89, 5, 5, 5, 322, 7, 6, 6, 6, 102]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
[int(i) if int(i)==i else i for i in my_lst]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 1, 1.43, 1, 8, 4, 8.98, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 72, 3, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 4, 4, 4, 
 4, 8.7, 43, 5.89, 5, 5, 5, 322, 7, 6, 6, 6, 102]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```py
[int(i) if i.is_integer() else i for i in my_list]
```